# VBA vlookup for entire column

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am very new to VBA and this is my first time posting here. I am trying to get a macro to add two columns that use vlookup to find a value from another workbook. Eventually I want to have the macro cycle through an entire folder of files to process, so I can't have the worksheet on the same workbook.

So far I have:

```
Range("K1:L1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("K1") = "Rank"
Range("L1") = "Distance"
Range("K2:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula =  Application.VLookup(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9)), Workbooks("SOSP.nearestGHCND.simple.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:F"), 2, False)
```

I think there is something wrong with the references, but I'm having a hard time finding how to properly format it online. Also

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the cell address for the *<lookup_value>* in the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)? While you have used direct referencing for almost all of the worksheet and cell references, the *<lookup_value>* parameter is left as `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9)`.

Comment: The lookup value is 9 columns to the left of the formula. How should I be referencing it? Thanks for the speedy reply.

Comment: The way that is written is that VBA resolved the `Application.Vlookup` and puts the value into the cells. If you do that and want it to reflect individual rows for the *<lookup_value>* then you have to loop through them. If you want to actually put a formula into the cells and let the worksheet calculation resolve the formula(s) that is another matter.

Comment: I originally had it as a formula but it was taking a really long time. Do you have any ideas on how to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inquiring about *'...how to make it faster?*' it is always a good idea to include as much information as you possibly can. Loading the external workbook's *<table_array>* into a variable should help but depending on the number of rows, it will still take some time to loop through them.

```
    Dim lr As Long, rw As Long, extRNG As Range

    'the following assumes that SOSP.nearestGHCND.simple.xlsx is open
    Set extRNG = Workbooks("SOSP.nearestGHCND.simple.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:F")

    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("K:L").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("K1:L1") = Array("Rank", "Distance")
    For rw = 2 To lr
        Cells(rw, 11) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 2), extRNG, 2, False)
    Next rw

    Set extRNG = Nothing
```

To avoid the loop you could bulk write the formula into the entire column but the external reference will slow the formula down. You might start loading the ranges (e.g. *<lookup_range>* and *<table_array>*) into arrays and process that way then return the values en masse back to the worksheet. Anything over ~65K rows would likely have to be transposed. There is no mention of what to do with column L. The nature of the data (numbers vs text vs other) is a consideration. What percentage of the time the values are expected to be found is another consideration.

Sample data complete with expected results is the best recourse. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Another option is to get it working to some level of satisfaction and then repost the working code at SE's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) and ask for suggestions on where it can be improved.